# Capturing the dns server ip from an http web request

Tags: asp.net, dns, ip, httprequest, trace

Is there any way to capture the DNS server IP Address that resolves the HTTP web request? The DNS server's IP need to be obtained when a user makes request to the web server. I am using an ASP.NET web application.

Comment: This sounds strange, why do you need the IP address of the DNS server used to resolve the hostname? You have no way of knowing that in your server. If you are asking for the hostname or IP address of the user accessing your website, use `Request.UserHostAddress`.

Comment: Your local DNS server would handle that job for you. Why do you need to know which DNS server *actually* resolved it?

Comment: I wanted to check whether the request has come via a rouge DNS server or not

Comment: You can get help from here to obtain DNS IP address http://stackoverflow.com/a/424367/1209450

Comment: Here is another link http://stackoverflow.com/a/424521/1209450

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot determine what DNS server was used to resolve your websites domain on a clients machine. You can however get the clients IP address.

This is why things like [SOPA's DNS filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_Online_Piracy_Act#Domain_Name_System) are dangerous. People will use "rogue" DNS servers to bypass the filtering, and by doing so expose themselves to all sorts of phishing attacks.

The DNS server must be able to be trusted.

Comment: I wanted to check whether the request has come via a rouge DNS server or not.

Comment: Answer is still no, the DNS server told the client that your websites IP address is "this" and then their browser connected to your site. There is no way to intercept that information from your website.

Comment: Just to point out an example, the site www.dns-ok.us seem to do this kind of checks and verifies whether the dns server that we use is not a rouge one.

Comment: This is a guess but it's probably doing a secondary request going to a known address that would be affected by that particular DNS Changer attack. If the target resolves as expected, green is shown.

Comment: I had tested that site by setting my DNS servers in ip configuration to one of those rouge ip lists and this site had turned red detecting the rouge server. But when I use the DNS from my ISP, it will show green status. I didn't quite understand what you meant by doing a secondary request to a known address.

Comment: Meaning the site probably asks your browser to access an address that was known to be affected by that particular attack. So it's not checking the DNS server IP your using, it's using the known exploited addresses to figure it out. Again, I'm speculating.